# How to reset mysql root password without logging into mysql?

Tags: password, mysql

I want to reset mysql root password but I don't want to log into mysql and then reset the password just as follows,

```
  mysql -u root
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
  UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

Is there a way to achieve this using external command or something?

Comment: You could enter the above lines in a text file and use a command like `mysql -u root < resetpassword.txt`. Or you could restart the server with `mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/resetpassword.txt &`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-x.x
```

Replace x.x with your current mysql server version.

Than it will prompt for a new password.

Answer (score 0):

Try follows:

`mysqladmin -u root password **your-new-password**`

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

`mysql -u root -p`

Give password to enter mysql.